# How to print Unicode codepoints as characters in C?

Tags: c, file-io, unicode, utf-8

I have an array of `uint32_t` elements that each store a codepoint for a non-latin Unicode character. How do I print them on the console or store them in a file as UTF-8 encoded characters? I understand that they may fail to render properly on a console, but they should display fine if I open them in a compatible editor.

I have tried using `wprintf(L"%lc", UINT32_T_VARIABLE)`, and `fwprintf(FILE_STREAM, L"%lc", UINT32_T_VARIABLE)` but to no avail.

Comment: Did you make sure `stdout` was not byte-oriented?

Comment: @EOF: actually `stdout` must be byte oriented and the proper locale must be selected for this work.

Comment: @chqrlie: Not if you want to use `wprintf()` as the OP apparently does.

Comment: @EOF: The OP tried using `wprintf()` for his purpose, but he does not necessarily want to use the wide string versions, he merely wants to convert Unicode codepoints to UTF-8.

Answer (score 3):

Best to use existing code when available.

Rolling ones own Unicode code-point to [UTF8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is simply, yet easy to mess up.  The answer took 2 edits to fix. [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38491380/how-to-print-unicode-codepoints-as-characters-in-c/38492214?noredirect=1#comment64386806_38492214) [@chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38491380/how-to-print-unicode-codepoints-as-characters-in-c/38492214?noredirect=1#comment64412256_38492214), so rigorous testing is recommended for any self-coded solution.  Follows is lightly tested code to convert a code-point to an array.
Note that the result is not a *string*.

```
// Populate utf8 with 0-4 bytes
// Return length used in utf8[]
// 0 implies bad codepoint
unsigned Unicode_CodepointToUTF8(uint8_t *utf8, uint32_t codepoint) {
  if (codepoint <= 0x7F) {
    utf8[0] = codepoint;
    return 1;
  }
  if (codepoint <= 0x7FF) {
    utf8[0] = 0xC0 | (codepoint >> 6);
    utf8[1] = 0x80 | (codepoint & 0x3F);
    return 2;
  }
  if (codepoint <= 0xFFFF) {
    // detect surrogates
    if (codepoint >= 0xD800 && codepoint <= 0xDFFF) return 0;
    utf8[0] = 0xE0 | (codepoint >> 12);
    utf8[1] = 0x80 | ((codepoint >> 6) & 0x3F);
    utf8[2] = 0x80 | (codepoint & 0x3F);
    return 3;
  }
  if (codepoint <= 0x10FFFF) {
    utf8[0] = 0xF0 | (codepoint >> 18);
    utf8[1] = 0x80 | ((codepoint >> 12) & 0x3F);
    utf8[2] = 0x80 | ((codepoint >> 6) & 0x3F);
    utf8[3] = 0x80 | (codepoint & 0x3F);
    return 4;
  }
  return 0;
}

// Sample usage
uint32_t cp = foo();
uint8_t utf8[4];
unsigned len = Unicode_CodepointToUTF8(utf8, cp);
if (len == 0) Handle_BadCodePoint();
size_t y = fwrite(utf8, 1, len, stream_opened_in_binary_mode);
```

Comment: The correct range for the high and low surrogates is U+D800 .. U+DFFF (split into high surrogates U+D800 .. U+DBFF and low surrogates U+DC00 .. U+DFFF) rather than U+D000 .. U+DFFF as in one version of the code in the answer.  The chart for [U+AC00 .. U+D7AF](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UAC00.pdf) covers Hangul Syllables.  As you said, it's easy to mess it up.

Comment: The code is incorrect for the intermediary sequence bytes in the 3 and 4 byte cases: you must mask off the `0x40` bit after shifting `codepoint`... *simple, yet easy to mess up* indeed.

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, bit needed clearing (in 2 byte case too) - code amended.

Answer (score 2):

You must first select the proper locale with:

```
#include <locale.h>

setlocale(LC_ALL, "C.UTF-8");
```

or

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
```

And then use `printf` or `fprintf` with the `%lc` format:

```
printf("%lc", UINT32_T_VARIABLE);
```

This will work only for Unicode code points small enough to fit in a `wchar_t`.  For a more complete and portable solution, you may nee to implement the Unicode to UTF-8 conversion yourself, which is not very difficult.

Comment: Setting locale does not help. `fprintf()` and `wprintf()` only print/store blank space, and `fwprintf()` stores incorrect characters on the file.

Comment: What are your platform and compiler?

Comment: Win10, gcc 5.3, Cygwin

Comment: The support for locale and multibyte encoding is in the C library.  On Windows, you may use either the MSVC runtime library or the Cygwin specific C library, derived from the Glibc, which I believe has better support.  To avoid this issue, use your own UTF-8 converter.